# Why is the cube whiter when I am in pencil mode or edit mode? And how to fix it?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Why is the cube whiter when I am in pencil mode or edit mode? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By default the "Fade Inactive Geometry" option is turned on in the viewport overlays in draw mode or edit mode for grease pencil objects.  You can turn it off to go back to the lighting that would otherwise be used in your viewport shading mode.

[image]